# PCRE/PHP regex not matching last "item"

Tags: php, regex, pcre

Here's a regex that I've cobbled up:

```
/(.*={76}\s)?\s*(.*?)\s\-\-\s(\d{2}\/\d{2}\-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2})\s\s(.*?)\s(http:\/\/service.*?)\s(\-{76})/is
```

and here's the text I will be parsing: http://p.linode.com/7015

and here's the replacement for the matched text:

```
<item>\n\t<title>$2</title>\n\t<pubDate>$pubDate</pubDate>\n\t<description>$4</description>\n\t<link>$5</link>\n</item>\n\n
```

and finally, here's the output that I get: http://p.linode.com/7016

I have *almost* come up with a regex needed to parse a block of text into RSS 2.0 XML markup. I've tested it with [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) and RegexBuddy and it works perfectly *except* for the last "item" where there is no line breaks after the link ([Line 269](http://p.linode.com/7015)).

In short, **the problem is the "iProperty" article in the text is not matched**.

Any regex gurus willing to help me troubleshoot what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've try and I think I've got the solution (I can generate the correct output file with it), just modify your regex like this :

```
/(.*={76}\s)?\s*(.*?)\s\-\-\s(\d{2}\/\d{2}\-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2})\s\s(.*?)\s(http:\/\/service.*?)(\s(\-{76})|$)/is
```

I've just added the `|$` at the end and some `()` for the OR statement.